# How to Kill a component in Angular?

Tags: angular, components

I have 3 Components A, B, and C in my angular project. I have used default routing

'''

'''

I am navigating from A-> B -> C and C is my result page. What I observed is even though I am at C, component A is still running in the background. How to kill A here?

Answer (score 0):

Your component should implement `OnDestroy` interface, than inside `ngOnDestroy` you may want to unsubscribe observables.

Comment: I am following the OnDestroy lifecycle hook, but its a simple component without observables.

Comment: I missing some information, how to you know that he is still alive?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
//ParentComponent
@ViewChild(MyComponent) myComponentRef: ComponentRef<MyComponent>;

And my "destroy" call:

private ngOnDestroy () {
    this.myComponentRef.destroy();
}
```

Comment: Actually there nothing like Parent-Child relation, all the 3 components are working independently but getting displayed sequentially